# How to join efficiently 2 Spark dataframes partitioned by some column, when that column is one of multiple join keys?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently facing some issues in Spark 3.0.2 to efficiently join 2 Spark dataframes when

1. The 2 Spark DataFrames are partitioned by some key `id`;
2. `id` is part of the join key, but it is not the only one.

My intuition is telling me that the query optimizer is, in this case, not choosing the optimal path. I will illustrate my issue through a minimal example (note that this particular example does *not* really require a join, it's just for illustrative purposes).

Let's start from the simple case: the 2 dataframes are partitioned by `id`, and we join by `id` only:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Make up some test dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(id=i // 10, order=i % 10, value=i) for i in range(10000)])

# Create the left side of the join (repartitioned by id)
df2 = df.repartition(50, 'id')

# Create the right side of the join (also repartitioned by id)
df3 = df2.select('id', F.col('order').alias('order_alias'), F.lit(0).alias('dummy'))

# Perform the join
joined_df = df2.join(df3, on='id')
joined_df.foreach(lambda x: None)
```

This results in the following efficient plan:
[image]

This plan is efficient: it recognizes that the 2 dataframes are already partitioned by the join key and avoids to re-shuffle them. The 2 dataframes are not only repartitioned, but also colocated.

What happens if there is an additional join key? It results in an inefficient plan:

```
joined_df = df2.join(df3, on=[df2.id==df3.id, df2.order==df3.order_alias])
joined_df.foreach(lambda x: None)
```

[image]

The plan is inefficient since it is repartitioning the 2 dataframes to do the join. This does not make sense to me. Intuitively, we could use the existing partitions: all keys to be joined will be found in the same partition as before, there is just one additional condition to apply! So I thought: perhaps we could phrase the 2nd condition as a filter?

```
joined_df.foreach(lambda x: None)

joined_df = df2.join(df3, on='id')

joined_df_filtered = joined_df.filter(df2.order==df3.order_alias)
```

This however results in the same inefficient plan, since Spark query optimizer will just merge the 2nd filter with the join.

So, I finally thought that maybe I could force Spark to process the join as I want by adding a dummy cache step, by trying the following:

```
from pyspark import StorageLevel
joined_df = df2.join(df3, on='id')

# Note that this storage level will not cache anything, it's just to suggest to Spark that I need this intermediate result
joined_df.persist(StorageLevel(False, False, False, False))

# Do the filtering after "persisting" the join
joined_df_filtered = joined_df.filter(df2.order==df3.order_alias)
joined_df_filtered.foreach(lambda x: None)
```

This results in an efficient plan! It is in fact much faster than the previous ones.
[image]

The workaround of "persisting" the first join to force Spark to use a more efficient processing plan is "good enough" for my use case, but I still have a few questions:

1. Am I missing something in my intuition that Spark should actually be reusing partitions when the partition key is part of the join key, instead of re-shuffling?
2. Is this expected behavior of the query optimizer? Should a ticket be filed for it?
3. Is there a better way to force the desired processing plan than adding the "persist" step? It seems more like an indirect workaround than a direct solution.

Comment: If you run this without persist, but with join by id and filter by order in separate steps - what's the plan then?

Comment: that's what I run just before the code with persist, see the comment above it: it is the same plan as when joining by the 2 keys.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read carefully. I was struggling with the same some time ago in Spark 2.3, pity that it's still unsolvable with 3.0 :)

Comment: But I think it's because optimizer doesn't have a clue about distribution of data in dataset. You have 10 records per id and when joining by id only that makes 100 records in memory before it's filtered. That could be 10000 records per id, blowing up memory on join.

Comment: It would be a good idea to be able to force partitioning column via hint, but I tried also with `REPARTITION(id)` and it didn't work in this case. This could be a potential feature request.

Comment: So finally, `persist` is a good trick as apparently the only thing that can work now. It would have saved me some pain if I knew this before :)

Comment: thanks! I think that your reasoning is correct, joining by id and then filtering could potentially blow up memory usage. However, the key issue is another one: the optimizer could do the join with the 2 keys exactly the same way that it does it in the inefficient plan, but without repartitioning. The keys to join will already guaranteed to be in the partitions corresponding to the first id.

Comment: I also agree with your comment that it would be good to be able to force the partitioning column for the joins, but the hint doesn't work. As I see it, there are 2 possible feature requests: asking for some option to specify a partitioning column for the join, or make sure that the optimizer doesn't repartition in these cases.

Comment: About `persist` - I'm glad if it helps others! I just had the intuition that, if Spark is informed that you need that intermediate dataframe, then it must choose the plan we want.